# Destroying an object after a distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a platform generator method which looks like this:

```
  void SpawnBuilding()
{
    float space = Random.Range(0, distanceBetweenBuildings);


    float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, player.transform.position);

    if (instantiationDistance > distance && canInstantiate)
    {
        Instantiate(this.gameObject, transform.GetChild(0).transform.position + new Vector3(space, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        canInstantiate = false;
    }
    else if(distance < destroyDistance)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

}
```

}

Basically how it works is if the player is close enough, every platform generates another platform right next to it. But I also want to destroy the platforms if the distance is too low. What I mean by that is for example, if platform - player = -25 or lower, destroy the platform. Destroy behaviour doesn't work at all, what could be the problem ?

Comment: What are the values of `distance` and `destroyDistance` (you can find this with the debugger) when you expect the object to be destroyed?

Comment: I set up `destroyDistance` via editor. I give it a negative value and want to calculate the negative distance between each platform and the player, and if the distance is smaller than the  `destroyDistance`, I want to destroy that platform. But the  `distance` is always the distance between the last platform and the player, so I can't seem to calculate the distance between EACH platform & the player.

Comment: If I am correct, Vector3.Distance() doesn't return negative values.

Comment: Hmm, that's correct, wonder what could I use instead.

Comment: Instead compare the distance with positive values. You can also use trigger colliders.

Comment: @No-LifeDev why even at the first place your `DestroyDistance` is a negative number, you wanna see that it it is close or not, right, so why not use a positive value?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new variable which looks like `Vector3 newVector = v1 - v2` and it returns a negative value needed.